# How can I get a Canvas component of a ListGridRecord?

Tags: java, list, grid, record, smartgwt

I use smartgwt 2.4.

I'm trying to style a `ListGridRecord`. I want to get the Canvas component of it, but I cannot find a reference anywhere.

I know there are methods in `ListGrid` as `createRecordComponent` or `getBackgroundComponent` etc., but these don't return any component. They are meant as an override point (user can define his/her own components instead of default). But this is not what I want. I want to get the default component and change it (style it).

I know there's a `setCellFormatter` method at the `ListGrid`, where I can set format of a cell, but it only regards the text component of a cell, not the whole row (record).

I know there's a `getBaseStyle` method, where I can put a class name, but this is still not what I want. I want to change the style dynamically (e.g. I want to put any background color to the component) not only put a static class(es) (where the background color is predefined).

Can anybody help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your options are a little limited when it comes to SmartGWT.
One, although not very simple way of achieving that is overriding the [ListGrid.getCellCSSText(ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum)](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#getCellCSSText%28com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGridRecord,%20int,%20int%29) method on creation of ListGrid as shown [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/CellwithstyleSmartGWT.htm).
That is how I have created customized cell styles.

```
final ListGrid grid= new ListGrid() {
    protected String getCellCSSText(ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum) {
        if (getFieldName(colNum).equals("MyColumnName")) {
            ListGridRecord record = (ListGridRecord) record;
            if (record.getSomeValue() > 20) {
                return "font-weight:bold; color:red;";
            } else if (record.getSomethingElse() < 5) {
                return "font-weight:bold; color:blue;";
            } else {
                return super.getCellCSSText(record, rowNum, colNum);
            }
        } else {
            return super.getCellCSSText(record, rowNum, colNum);
        }
    }
};
```